# ffmpeg streaming runs ineeficiently when started via init.d startup script

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffmpeg, sysvinit, cpu-usage

I'm using ffmpeg to stream video/audio on raspberry pi 4, using the following command

```
ffmpeg -re -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -thread_queue_size 512 -i ${video_device} -re -f alsa -thread_queue_size 512 -itsoffset 0 -i "default:CARD=C920" -acodec aac -vf drawtext="fontsize=48: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=2: fontcolor=white: x=(w-text_w)/1.1: y=((h-text_h)/1.4)+((h-text_h)/4): text='%{localtime\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}'" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 256k -r 10 -tune zerolatency -strict -2 -f mpegts -flush_packets 1 udp://192.168.116.13:5000?pkt_size=512
```

If I run this code manually, it works well (streaming is good with 1-2 second latency).

In order to start it automatically at startup, I prepared an *init.d* script and used *update-rc.d*. No issues so far. If I start the script manually using

```
sudo service myscript start
```

I get the same good performance. But when it start at boot, streaming performance is bad (there is ~10 latency in sound, sometimes sound breaks, other times video pauses...).

I run

```
ps aux
```

both for manual start and automated start. Interesting part, when it is started at boot up, CPU use is much lower (87.3%) than manual start (189%), which may mean that manual start uses more threads thus resulting in better performance.

Any ideas on why I get worse streaming performance when I start streaming at boot up? And how to correct this?

UPDATE (after @JonasBerlin's comment):

In both cases (manual start and start at boot), I run the command as the user *pi*.

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd
```

gives following outputs.

With manual start (good streaming performance, high CPU use)

```
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 1 -> 'socket:[18561]'
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 2 -> 'socket:[18561]'
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 3 -> /dev/video0
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 4 -> /dev/snd/timer
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 5 -> /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:30 6 -> 'socket:[17677]'
```

With start at boot (bad streaming performance, low CPU use)

```
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 1 -> 'socket:[16471]'
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 2 -> 'socket:[16471]'
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 3 -> /dev/video0
lr-x------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 4 -> /dev/snd/timer
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 5 -> /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Feb  7 15:29 6 -> 'socket:[17332]'
```

Comment: Can you do `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` for both situations? I'm wondering whether the output goes to some place that is "slow" to accept data..

Comment: @JonasBerlin, I updated the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks; it unfortunately didn't reveal anything :(